Role permissions to trigger SQL Server Service Broker
We have a Service Broker that listens for changes to the database and then sends messages to a queue based on the changed data.  This works if the logged in user is has a server role of sysadmin or db_owner. We want this to work for other users as well but do not want them to have sysadmin or db_owner level permissions.  I created a new role but I am unsure what permissions I need to grant to allow the service broker to work.  Any thoughts?
I created a new role and gave my test user membership in that role.  I have granted the role receive on the queues and send on the services.  such as:
GRANT RECEIVE ON [dbo].[QueryNotificationErrorsQueue] to [db_servicebrokeruser]
GRANT RECEIVE ON [dbo].[EventNotificationErrorsQueue] to [db_servicebrokeruser]
GRANT RECEIVE ON [dbo].[ServiceBrokerQueue] to [db_servicebrokeruser]

GRANT SEND ON SERVICE:: [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotificationService] to [db_servicebrokeruser]
GRANT SEND ON SERVICE:: [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/ServiceBroker] to [db_servicebrokeruser]
GRANT SEND ON SERVICE:: [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/EventNotificationService] to [db_servicebrokeruser]

I still don't see the messages flowing to the queue and I don't see any errors either.

SB setup can be tricky. Can you also include the rest of your configuration? At least the Service and Queue definitions. Related, what happens if you try to send a message as the test user outside of the trigger?

Please include the code that sends the messages and the ev. errors it gets
